# Does anyone know the expression "Aye Gannies" (or perhaps the spelling is "I gonees")

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms, slang, colloquialisms

Growing up in the Missouri Ozarks we had a neighbor named Hicks who used this expression.  One of Mr. Hick's frequent and unique expressions was, “I Gannies” (the “a” was short).  The only other times I’ve run across the expression were on the old radio show, “Lum and Abner” and in the book, “Little Shepard of Kingdom Come.” I wish I knew origin or meaning of the expression.

Comment: [The Lum and Abner thing](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D-QzEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT165&ots=FBxFDLji8j&dq=%E2%80%9CLum%20and%20Abner%E2%80%9D%20gannies&pg=PT101#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CLum%20and%20Abner%E2%80%9D%20gannies&f=false) [seems to be](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Radio_Program_Openings_and_Closings_1931/GoneCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E2%80%9CLum%20and%20Abner%E2%80%9D%20grannies&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover) either "I grannies" or "By grannies". I've no idea what that means, other than being some kind of exclamation in Arkansas slang.

Answer (score 12):

From   M. Montgomery and J. Heinmiller (eds.); *Dictionary of Southern Appalachian English* (2021):

> [**ay** (also **aye, ey, i**)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Southern_Appalachian_Engli/J8_9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aye%20grannies%22&pg=PT216&printsec=frontcover)  *interjection* Used as a mild exclamation or oath to express a range of emotion (affirmation,
> surprise, acknowledgement, regret, consternation, etc.), usually as a
> combination form, as in *aye God, **aye gonnies**, aye grain, **aye
> grannies**, aya jallus, aya jucks, ey God, **ey gonnies**, I God, I golly,
> **I gonnies, I grannies, I growneys.*** See also **by, dad-, eh la.**

The next paragraph has citations for the above, including:

> **1931.** Combs *Lg Sthn High* 1308 "Cuss-word" expressions of surprise and intense expression [incude] **I (by) gonnies**.
>
> **1939** Hall *Coll*: ***ey gonnies*** = said to be a common byword of some people.
>
> **1995-97** Montgomery *Coll* **Aye gonnies**, I ain't gonna do it

Other Google Book [snippets](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Southern_Appalachian_Engli/J8_9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22grannies%22) with *grannies* that came up searching this work include:

> (also **grannies**) interjection Used in phrases to form mild
> oaths...Granny alive, Granny sakes...**I grannies**—I can dance a jig
> ...
>
> aye grain, **aye grannies**, sometimes used as a sort of resignation
> to events, a fatalistic expression... now the common northern
> exclamation of surprise, invocation, earnestness
> ...
>
> Unlike most healers who are shrouded in mystery and secretiveness,
> **grannies** are usually quick to dispense the knowledge how to "cure what ails ya"...

I haven't come across anything that shines light on the relationship between *gannies*, *grannies*, *gonnies*, and *growneys*; however, snippets are often incomplete.

---

> Some of these expressions, which would be a big improvement over the
> needless profanity of our day, are: **By** or **aye grannies**, by or
> aye gravies, by or aye grabs, dad burn it, dad gum it, dog take it,
> dog gone it, by George, by Ned... [Harold Stephens; *Echoes of a Passing
> Era*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Echoes_of_a_Passing_ERA_Down_Memories_La/QQnXVjLoLNQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22aye%20grannies%22&dq=%22aye%20grannies%22&printsec=frontcover) (1971)

> ... I could hear their hoarse voices, while from the bed my
> grandfather could also be heard: "**I gannies!** It's a tie score!...Pitch
> 'em, Bill! Missed, goldarn it!" [Elizabeth Spencer; *Landscapes of the
> Heart*, p.16](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Landscapes_of_the_Heart/th9fDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I%20gannies%22&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> The boys said Lieutenant Dick never gave but one order, and that was:
> “**I gannies**, boys, come on!" That made him a fine reputation.
> [*Confederate Veteran, Vol. 19, p.511*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Confederate_Veteran/m8E_AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I%20gannies%22&pg=PA511&printsec=frontcover) (1911)

> "Watch me hit those crazy bees, Felix."
> ...
> **Aye gannies**, I knocked
> the props out from under some of them," Dan said. A second later a pig
> squealed. [Elizabeth Spences; *Fire in the Morning*, p.92](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fire_in_the_Morning/GukaBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aye%20gannies%22&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Without hesitation, I swallowed the aspirin before moving back down in my bed, closing my eyes, drifting off. Looking like a humongous
> green crab apple, I popped out from between my mama's legs.
>
> "**Aye
> grannies**!"  the midwife hollered when she saw me. "You have birthed
> a great big crab apple."
>
> "Oh, Lordy!" my mama screamed. [Gwyn Rubio; *Icy Sparks*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Icy_Sparks/XG6-eP4-UxsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aye%20grannies%22&pg=PA148&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> OPEN (1948)
>
> **SOUND**: Phone rings.
> **LUM**: **By grannies**, Abner, I believe that's our
> ring.
> **ANNOUNCER** (Wendell Niles): Frigidaire, a division of General Motors, presents *The New Lum and Abner Show*. Tonight, ...
>
> [Vincent Terrace; *Radio Program Openings and Closings,
> 1931-1972*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Radio_Program_Openings_and_Closings_1931/GoneCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=lum%20and%20abner%20gannies&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> It may be that outlanders have brought in new ideas about some of these things, along with their comfortable retirement incomes. You hear a lot of non-Arkansas voices these days in the Ouachitas. At
> Lum and Abner's Jot-em-Down Store in Pine Ridge, I was greeted by a
> nice lady from some northern clime who never in her life said, "Well I
> swan!" much less, "**Ay grannies!**" [Charles Portis and Jay Jennings;
> *Escape Velocity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Escape_Velocity/4xKEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ay%20grannies%22&pg=PT120&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

Comment: I had always assumed it was "agonies". I spent three summers working in the Ozarks on the Missouri-Arkansas state line listening to this.

Answer (score 2):

***DARE's discussion of the 'gonnies' family***

*Dictionary of American Regional English* (1992) has this entry under the heading "gonnies":

> **gonnies** n Also *gannies*, *ganny*, *gonies* {Euphem varr of *God*; cf **Guinea** n<sup>3</sup> ["Euphem for *God*; cf *E[nglish] D[ialect] D[ictionary]* *guiny* 'An expletive'"]} **chiefly Sth, S midl** Cf **i** prep ["By reduction of *by* in exclam phrr *by God*, *by Jesus* and varr (often with minced forms), but cf also **ay** or **ah** intj in similar phrr"]
>
> In phr *I gonnies* and varr: By golly!—used as an exclam of surprise, annoyance, confirmation, etc.
>
> {first cited occurrences:] **1907** Wright *Shepherd* 285 **swMO, Ozarks**, I seed the blamdest {sic} sight las' night that ever was in these woods, I reckon. I gonies! Hit was a plumb wonder! **1916** *D[ialect] N[otes]* 4.344 **seSC** I ganny I got Indian blood in me. **1931** *P[ublications of the] M[odern] Language] A[ssociation of America]* 46.1308 **s.Appalachians**, "Cuss-words," expressions of surprise and intense expressions ... i (by) gonnies. **1937** (1963) Hyatt *Kiverlid* 66 **KY**, "I gonnies!" complained Calhoun, "hit's a plumb botherment about that boy gettin' my cart busted up." **1940** *Amer. Mercury* June 211/1 **Sth**, I knowed of a baby once larnt to smoke in the cradle. Ruther draw on a pipe than a tit. Aye gonnies, if that little 'un didn't grow up six feet two. ...

"Wright" is Harold Bell Wright, [*The Shepherd of the Hills*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bqCvb9GG2QIC&pg=PA315&dq=%22I+gonies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicyd3I2v32AhXnJzQIHRaeCw4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20gonies%22&f=false) (1909), in which two different characters use the expression a total of three times (one of them twice, in rapid succession):

> Preachin' Bill says "There's a heap o' difference in most men, but Jim Lane now he's more different than ary man you ever seed. Ain't no better neighbor'n Jim anywhere. Ride out o' his way any time t' do you a favor. But you bet there ain't ary man lives can ask Jim any fool questions while Jim's a lookin' at him. Tried it onct myself. Jim was a waitin' at th' ferry fer Wash Gibbs, an' we was a talkin' 'long right peart 'bout crops an' th' weather an' such, when I says, says I, like a dumb ol' fool, 'How'd you like it down in Texas, Jim, when you was there that time?' **I gonies**! His jaw shet with a click like he'd cocked a pistol, an' that look o' hisn, like he was seein' plumb through you, come int' his eyes, an' he says, says he, quiet like, 'D' you reckon that rain over on James yesterday raised th' river much?' An' 'fore I knowed it, I was tellin' him how that ol' red bull o' mine treed the Perkins boys when they was a possum huntin'."
>
> ...

> "Talkin' 'bout new fangled things, though, men! I seed the blamdest sight las' night that ever was in these woods, I reckon. **I gonies**! Hit was a plumb wonder!" Kicking one foot from the wooden stirrup and hitching sideways in the saddle, he [Lou Gordon, a rural mail carrier] prepared for an effort.
>
> "Little feller, he is. Ain't as tall as Preachin' Bill even, an' fat! **I gonies**! he's as fat as a possum 'n 'simmon time. He don't walk, can't; just naturally waddles on them little duck legs o' hisn. An' he's got th' prettiest little ol' face; all red an' white, an' as round's a walnut; an' a fringe of th' whitest hair you ever seed. An' clothes! Say, men."

---

***Early instances of 'I ganny' and related forms in the wild***

The earliest instance of the expression that I've been able to find is from Henry Austin, "[My Pilgrim Fathers](https://books.google.com/books?id=11Viac3vPykC&pg=PA483&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr65X26v32AhXVJzQIHUmRDOM4ChDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false)," in *The Southern Bivouac* (January 1887), where it appears in the form "I ganny":

> Some of the sentences passed by the General Court on general offenders about this time are as amusing as those of my friend Judge Walker, of Mississippi, who once sentenced a man to banishment, and one reprimanded a culprit for pleading guilty on a second appearance for a similar offense in the following trms: "What do you mean, sah? I reco'nize you as bein' befoah this yere court a year ago, sah, and pleadin' guilty then, sah. But, **I ganny**, you can't play that game twicet on this yere court. I'm a-gwine to try you, sah, and 'zamine the witnesses, sah, and find out, sah, whether you're guilty or not!"

From William Brown, "[Herne the Hunter](https://books.google.com/books?id=lLzQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA425&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr65X26v32AhXVJzQIHUmRDOM4ChDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false)," in *Outing* (February 1889):

> "What can be the matter with him? Do you know him?"
>
> "I knows more of him 'n I wants ter," replied the lad. "Oh, marm, that's old Herne, 'nd we uns air the fust ones ez hev be'n in hyar whar he stays. **I ganny!** I thort shore he'd hev yeaten ye up."

Similarly, from "A Mississippian," "[The Two Cronies](https://books.google.com/books?id=ObVNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA447&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkne2Z4_32AhWYFzQIHU9bDO8Q6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false)," in *The Midland Monthly Magazine* (June 1899), where it occurs six times in the course of the story:

> Billy had no drinking habits, but smoked a cob pipe, and indulged in the use of by-words and expletives, by which he relieved himself in times of high mental pressure. They were: «**I Ganny**,» «Dad fetch it,» and «Corn twist it.»
>
> ...
>
> Someone passing by cried out: "Hello, Billy, what is the matter with your furrows?" His ringing reply from under the unbrella was: «**I Ganny**, the sun warped 'em, or Bob Lee was no General.»
>
> ...
>
> «I'll bag her yet» or «I'll string her yet» was his chuckling comment at the end of many a successful shot or haul. Sometimes it was «**I Ganny**, I've got her, or Bob Lee is no General.»
>
> ...
>
> «**I Ganny**,» said the victim afterwards to himself, «She wrapped me 'round her finger that day good fashion, or Stonewall Jackson was no fighter.»
>
> ...
>
> «Yes, sir» put in Billy; «and so I am. She will fool him yet, just like she did—well—**I Ganny**! Purvall will yet call himself Poorvall before that girl is done with him.»
>
> ...
>
> «She did, or Bob Lee was no general. Do you remember the day she whispered something to me by the water shelf? Well, that was it. **I Ganny**, it is so.»

From Harrison Robertson, [*The Inlander*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UwRMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA153&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkne2Z4_32AhWYFzQIHU9bDO8Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false) (1901):

> The other things were brought, compounded, and disposed of. "And now if you don't say that beats mint in your buttonhole," Cousin Jo observed as he drew his bandana across his lips, "I'll—**I ganny**! I'll agree never to touch another drop of it as long as I live!"

From Harrison Robertson (again), [*The Opponents*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mEceAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkne2Z4_32AhWYFzQIHU9bDO8Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false) (1902):

> "**I ganny**, that sounds like Sid Garrard! Come outn from under that hat an' lemme see 'f 't aint. Say what skylarkin' you up to now, Sid? Where'd you git them clo'es?"
>
> "Where'd you get that team?" Garrard laughed.
>
> "Well, you know I'm thes boun' to have a team 'bout this time o' year, when that old apple-tree by the smoke-'ouse gits ready fer business; so I went to work an' borrid the mare from Rude Wright an' the mule from Uncle Jesse Craik. Th' ain't no sich June-apple in the country as that airn, but I misdoubt me ef it pays fer thee time an' labor. **I ganny**! it took me mighty nigh a week to borry that team this year. ...

And from Sutton Griggs, [*The Hindered Hand: Or, The Reign of the Repressionist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kfw0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkne2Z4_32AhWYFzQIHU9bDO8Q6AF6BAgBEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20ganny%22&f=false) (1905):

> "Excuse me, Elder ; but that kind o' talk makes me sick. You are a good Christian man, I really think ; but like most cullud people you are too jam full o' patience an' hope. I'll be blessed if I don't b'lieve Job was a cullud man. **I ganny**, I got Indian blood in me and if they pester this kid they are goin' to hear sump'in' drap."

This appears to be the source of the that appears in a [1916 edition of *Dialect Notes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aHUKAAAAIAAJ&q=%22I+ganny%22&dq=%22I+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr65X26v32AhXVJzQIHUmRDOM4ChDoAXoECAIQAg), cited in *DARE*'s entry for *gonnies* (above).

An early instance of the form "I gonnies" appears in John Fox, [*The Little Shepherd of Kingdom Come*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OnA6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA115&dq=%22I+gonnies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBjd2M3v32AhW8FzQIHb5_CMAQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false), serialized in *Scribner's Magazine* (March 1903):

> "I got another one," he [Dan] shouted. And Chad fished silently. They were making ""a mighty big fuss," he thought, "over mighty small fish. If he just had a minnow an' had 'em down in the mountains, **'I Gonnies**, he'd show 'em what fishin' was!" But he began to have good luck as it was. Perch after perch he pulled out quietly, and he kept Snowball busy stringing them until he had five on the string.

This instance is interesting because the author uses an apostrophe before *I* to signify the loss of the consonant *b* from the source word *by*.

Another early match comes from V. C. Allen, [*Rhea and Meigs Counties (Tennessee) in the Confederate War*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6gRIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22I+gonnies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBjd2M3v32AhW8FzQIHb5_CMAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1908):

> After Lieutenant Armour was killed W. P. Thomison, Jr., became a Lieutenant in Company "C," and was as brave a man as carried a sword in the Confederate Army. The boys said that "Lieutenant Dick" only gave one command when ordered to advance on the enemy, and that was simply, "**I gonnies**, boys, come on."

This appears to be the same officer and saying noted in W. G. Allen, "[Reminiscences of Chickamauga](https://books.google.com/books?id=m8E_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA511&dq=%22I+gannies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVo8PA4f32AhU0JzQIHaGhDrgQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22I%20gannies%22&f=false)," in *Confederate Veteran* (November 1911), cited in DjinTonic's answer, except that in the latter account the expression is given as "I gannies." Whether W. G. Allen and V. C. Allen are relatives—or perhaps even the same person—is unclear.

---

***Early instances of 'by ganny' in the wild***

The large number of early instances of "I ganny" suggest that the ancestral from of the wording may have been "by ganny"—and this possibility finds support in some instances of the latter term from the 1860s.

From Charles Thomas, [*Adventures and Observations on the West Coast of Africa and Its Islands*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QBxOAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA205&dq=%22by+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1gPr28f32AhWWG80KHXV3BnsQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20ganny%22&f=false) (1860):

> It was our intention to visit some of the other schools of this denomination [Methodism] in the town, but when we reached the summit of a hill near the mission-house, we saw tthe sunset signal flying from our fore. The effect of such visits upon candid minds may be  seen in the following speech of our worthy *Saldado* captain, delivered at the mass-table a few days after. I hope that that benevolent gentleman will pardon me for telling this familiarly-expressed "tale out of school," but truth demands it. "I tell you what it is , gentlemen; I have often questioned the usefulness and the good sense of missions in Africa; but when I heard them little [indigenous children] at Cape Coast, singing those old Methodist hymns, that I used to hear on Long Island when I was a boy—and that wasn't yesterday—I thought, **by ganny**, 'Well, the Christian religion is bound to go over the whole earth!' Chaplain, I give in! OI apologize. **By ganny**, there's no use talking!"

From Emma Southworth, [*Fair Play, Or, The Test of the Lone Isle*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zxcnJU2q1LIC&pg=PA613&dq=%22by+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1gPr28f32AhWWG80KHXV3BnsQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20ganny%22&f=false) (1868):

> "**By ganny**!" said one gray old sea-dog as he passed, "if I could find a gal as spunky as that one, I'd spark her myself, old as I am!"

From Emma Southworth (again), [*How He Won Her*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qaJMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%22by+ganny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1gPr28f32AhWWG80KHXV3BnsQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20ganny%22&f=false) (1869):

> "It's just like that sulky, unsocial fellow, Wing—always poking himself off by himself; and yes, **by ganny**! always finding a place to poke himself into besides," growled the boy, as he settled himself to rest.

All three of these instances are from U.S. authors.

---

***Early instances of 'by gonny' and related forms in the wild***

Further searches find even earlier matches for the forms "by gonny," "by gony," and "by gonnies."

"By gonnies" appears earlier still. From the O'Hara Family, [*The Croppy; A Tale of 1798*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9DEUJsB4IMQC&pg=PA296&dq=%22by+gonnies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__e6rmv72AhW8HzQIHe-CDCEQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonnies%22&f=false) (1828):

> Why the worth o' this will make you tipsy, Davy, my boy."
>
> "Who cares, by gonnies ; an' there's another to back it, that my mother doesn't know about, your sowl."
>
> ...
>
> "Oh! I am as dhry as a fish, by gonnies!" said the weaver, in heavy ecstasy in anticipation of a treat he had not had for a long time, nor very frequently, at any time, indulged in.
>
> ...
>
> "My mother it was that put me on it," answer the suitor ; "she tould me to come over when the piece was worked ; an' she made me dhress myself in my grogram-grey an' all : an' **by gonnies**, coortin is plaisin enough," looking affectionately at the pewter pot—"an' my mother 'ill larn you to fix the tackle in the loom, Kitty, so she will."

Notably, this instance is published and/or set in Ireland, as are the four next-earliest instances that I found.

From John Banim, [*The Anglo-Irish of the Nineteenth Century: A Novel*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gvglAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA167&dq=%22by+gonnies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw-KORnf72AhWOIjQIHdoPB4M4ChDoAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonnies%22&f=false), volume 3 (1828):

> "Why, then, **by gonnies**! if they send me to gaol, Bignel will come and saze the ground."

From M. Archdeaon, [*Shawn Na Soggarth, The Priest Hunter ; An Irish Tale of the Penal Times*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JuNMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA237&dq=%22by+gonny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj5vjD9v32AhUxHjQIHWP9AMEQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonny%22&f=false) (1844):

> 'Did you think, you dunderhead,' says I, 'that I had the least notion of scrambling over bog and ditch, and you, with the scoff, to be along with me, when I made the bet.
>
> '**By Gonny**,' says Neddy, with a shout, though I always knew your honour to be as full o' thricks as an egg is o' mate, I didn't dhrame ye wor goin' to play so capityal a thrick, to-day.'

From Russell Graham, "[The Cellar in the Liberty, Dublin](https://books.google.com/books?id=8OwXAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA308&dq=%22by+gonies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGo-Pjxf72AhWfJzQIHVcHAC0Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonies%22&f=false)," in *Ainsworth's Magazine* (April 1845):

> "'**By gonies**! if it isn't a cat I saw, I'm afeard 'tis himself [the Croppy] was at the window,' muttered the undertaker. 'All the neighbours are in bed, and who else 'ud be stirring in the Liberty at this hour ov the night.' And with no little apprehension, he removed the things from the door, and th Croppy entered; vexation and anxiety adding to the natural upleasantness of his appearance.

From "[The Letter from Jack](https://books.google.com/books?id=6GsWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22by+gonny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj5vjD9v32AhUxHjQIHWP9AMEQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonny%22&f=false) in Dinny Blake, *The Sprig of Shillelah: A Collection of the Most Humorous and Popular Irish Songs* (1852):

> He came to the office and seen the Postmaster, / 'Oh lanna Machree, you've a letter for me, / It cam from my son—he has met some disaster, / He went to the Indies to skiver the blacks.' / 'What's yo[u]r name?' says the master, 'it's Murphy, my honey;' / 'All right—here it is—three and six is the money:' / 'Three and six-pence!' says Larry, 'that's too much **by gonny**, / To charge for that small scrap of paper of Jack's.' / Whack fol de , &c.

A glossary of Irish terms appended to this songbook includes an entry for "by gorra" (defined as "an exclamation")—which appears in two other songs in the collection—but not for "by gonny."

And finally from John Beauchamp Jones, [*Love and Money*](https://books.google.com/books?id=En8gAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA353&dq=%22by+gonny%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj5vjD9v32AhUxHjQIHWP9AMEQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gonny%22&f=false) (1865):

> "Hold on!" said Dick, crouching behind Timothy, when he saw Radley approaching."
>
> "**By gonny**!" said Tim, "if it's the one who's fastened your mammy in here, let's make him undo her!"
>
> ...
>
> ""Yes, **by gonny**! Mum! It's all clear as daylight. I'll swear I'm the son and heir——"

Jones was an American novelist, born in Baltimore, Maryland, but raised in Kentucky and Missouri, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Beauchamp_Jones).

---

***Early U.S. instances of 'by gorry' in the wild***

Whether "by gonny" and "by gorry" are directly related is unclear to me, but "by gorry" appears in the United States earlier than "by gonny" does.

From "[Militia System](https://books.google.com/books?id=ucj3Z2bBLDgC&pg=PA40&dq=%22by+gorry%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw55mrgf72AhV8HzQIHdt1CO44HhDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gorry%22&f=false)," originally published in the *[Pittsfield, Massachusetts] Berkshire American*, reprinted in the *[Boston, Massachusetts] New England Farmer* (August 22, 1828):

> *Col[onel Cantecuzena]*.—Eh?—Then you will wait one while, **by gorry**—and you may as well hang up your whistle as to think of rising like a Ponux, on the ashes of our glorious and unparalysed militia system.
>
> ...
>
> *Col.*—Well, if it [th militia system] must go, I'll fight for it till all is blue. Ay, sir, I'll stick to it to the last, as Lonidas did with his three hundred Spaniards at the Straits of Tremoppily ;—I'll never never give up the ship, **by gorry**.

From "[The Tea Fiend](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jyg2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA55&dq=%22by+gorry%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbuMvOjf72AhXZJDQIHWGrDTg4MhDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gorry%22&f=false)," in the *[Boston, Massachusetts] Amateur: A Journal of Literature an the Fine Arts* (August 7, 1830):

> In the name of the Lord, amen. Be it known to you, Colonel Leslie, if your name is Leslie, that none have a right to invade private property. Now this bridge was built by Elder Standfast Snooks, and Deacon Peter Smink, at their own cost and charges. If you chuse to pay the customary toll of three half-pence, Massachusetts currency, a head, you may pass over, but otherwise, **by gorry**, the draw shall not be lowered."

From "[Going a Courting](https://books.google.com/books?id=dY4eAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA306&dq=%22you+got+the+bag+By+gorry%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidtoGbjv72AhXJHzQIHfZHCbkQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22you%20got%20the%20bag%20By%20gorry%22&f=false)," in the *New York Constellation*, reprinted in the *[Boston, Massachusetts] Monthly Traveller or Spirit of the Periodical Press* (October 1830):

> If Barnabas had conceived high hopes before making his visit, the freedom of Patty's request in regard to carrying the milk, did not tend to lessen them; for he thus reasoned with himself—"Would she have taken this liberty, if she had not intended to stay with me? Surely not. I'm a fortunate feller if ever there was one. They wont say to me as they did to Tom Piper, t 'other day, 'you got the bag!' **By gorry**, I could'nt go that."

From "[Laughable Mistake](https://books.google.com/books?id=rOMRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA110&dq=%22by+gorry%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbuMvOjf72AhXZJDQIHWGrDTg4MhDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20gorry%22&f=false)," in the *New York Constellation*, reprinted in the *[Hudson, New York] Rural Repository* (December 4, 1830):

> The man was satisfied and went his way ; but the singularity of the mistake kept running in his head ; and meeting the same man the next day, and supposing that he had now found the bona fide doctor, whose physic had operated so wonderfully, he accosted him—'Would you believe it, doctor! I mistook your brother for you yesterday, and was a going to pay him for the physic you gin me—and **by gorry**, I never saw one man look so much like another, and yet not be him, in my life before!"

Other words attributed to the speaker in the above example—"divil" and "ither"—indicate that he is speaking with an Irish accent.

From "[Art of Selling](https://books.google.com/books?id=lbocAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA247&dq=%22shirts+by+gorry%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ9fP7kf72AhXFIDQIHd9CCwIQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22shirts%20by%20gorry%22&f=false)," in the *Philadelphia [Pennsylvania] Album and Ladies' Literary Port Folio* (July 30, 1831):

> "Can't we sell you some shirts?"
>
> "Shirts! **by gorry**, I can't afford to keep shirts and collars too."

---

*Conclusions*

The expression "aye gannies" in its multitude of forms ("ay gonnies," "I ganny," "I gonies," etc.) have made appearances in print since at least 1887, and the "ay/I" shortening of the first word in the expression seems to be an American linguistic innovation.

Instances of the ancestral form "by gannies/ganny/gonnies/gonny/gonies" appear in the U.S. at least as early as 1860—but the earliest instance U.S. instances are still more than three decades later than the earliest instances of the same phrase family in Ireland. Although the evidence isn't copious, it is consistent with the idea that "by gonnies/gonny/gony"  originated in Ireland, emigrated to North America in the mid-1800s, mutated into several new forms (including "by ganny/gannies") there, without losing its earlier Irish forms entirely, and then spun off several additional new forms that dropped the b from the opening word of the exclamation (*by*).

Although the similar sounding expression "by gorra"/"by gorry"/"begorra" also seems to have strong Irish roots and arrived in the U.S. by the late 1820s, the relationship between the "by gonny/ganny" family of variants and the "by gorra/gorry" family of variants is not well defined.

Comment: There's an interesting entry in [*The English dialect dictionary*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924088038397/page/676/mode/2up), page 676: **GONNER**,  *sb.*  Der.  Not.  Lin.  Also  in  form  **gonnies** Der.  Lin.  A  disguised  form  of  'God,'  used in a boy's oath. Examples: "Ooh,  by  Gonner, look what ah've fun!" // (J.P.K.)  Lin.  "By  gonnies!  we  were  light  of  foot".

Comment: Also, *April*, 1845 is correct for the entry (in *Ainsworth's Magazine*) you have cited. The entry, "The Cellar in the Liberty, Dublin, Part II" was added in April. (Part I was added in March). [[Source](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2608&context=uop_etds), page 78]

Comment: @Justin: Thank you for the additional notes. I have removed the parenthetical question mark from the April 1845 citation.

Comment: Nice job, Sven! Did you find any connection between, or mention of, any of your forms and *aye/I  grannies* (with an *R*)?

Comment: @DjinTonic: Thanks for asking about this. Unfortunately, I ran out of time and space in the answer that I was compiling and decide not to look into "ay/I/by granny/grannies" at all. I'm not at all sure that was a good idea, however, since I could have dropped the "by gorra/gorry" results instead. If I have time this evening, I'll check for "grannies"-related matches and (at least) note any relevant findings in a comment.

Comment: The earliest relevant match I found for "by grannies" is from Walter Jackson, "[How Summer Came to Sara Munro](https://books.google.com/books?id=vGgZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA435&dq=%22by+grannies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWja7i64D3AhXoJDQIHeAYCm04ChDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20grannies%22&f=false)," in _Arthur's Home Magazine_  (May 1892): "'Why, **by grannies**!' breaks from him [her husband] then. "If it aint Sara!" The two earliest Google Books matches for "I [or I] grannies" are from 1939 and involve [Lum and Abner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lum_and_Abner), ...

Comment: ... a radio comedy show duo. You can see snippet views of their banter with repeated use of the expression in [_Jot 'em Down Store: Catalogue, Calendar & Game and Party Book for 1939_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZSyRfkSS2hEC&q=%22I+grannies%22&dq=%22I+grannies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifg-L-ooH3AhX8GDQIHaa4BmsQ6AF6BAgEEAI) and [_Hardware Age_](https://books.google.com/books?id=iowTAQAAMAAJ&q=%22I+grannies%22&dq=%22I+grannies%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifg-L-ooH3AhX8GDQIHaa4BmsQ6AF6BAgCEAI).

Comment: Questions remains how *by/ay/i grannies* is related to the other expressions, whether  all  of these ultimately go back to a single word, and if that had a meaning other than, perhaps a euphemism (By God?)